# How to make a coutour plot with ggplot2 similar to filled.contour plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to create a contour plot with `ggplot2`, but my trial produces an empty plot. Please let me explain my situation:

First, I have 3D data (x, y, and z values; Please refer to the bottom of this question for my data). Here, I want to make a plot that includes z values as color gradation at x-y coordinates.

Based on this [page](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-warning-stat-contour-zero-contours-were-generated/111020/2), I know how to make a contour plot with `filled.contour` function.

```
library(akima)
fld <- with(df, interp(x = x, y = y, z = z))
filled.contour(x = fld$x,
               y = fld$y,
               z = fld$z)
```

This gives me a plot like below:
[image]

Now, I would like to create a similar plot with `ggplot2` package. When I tried the below code, it produced a empty plot:

```
gg <- ggplot() +
  stat_contour(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,z=z))
```

[image]

Would you please give me suggestions about data preparation, function usage, and how to produce a similar plot with `ggplot2`?

Based on this [page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html), `stat_contour` function can be used to make a similar plot, but I am not exactly sure how to do this.

I am looking forward to hearing about this.

PS. Here is my data

```
> df
          x        y        z
1  1030.480 22.24830 17.73213
2  1029.493 22.10948 18.90863
3  1030.746 22.95161 17.27875
4  1033.120 16.51953 15.84019
5  1029.090 24.40248 18.90565
6  1034.023 15.71038 14.95666
7  1030.350 26.83974 16.93909
8  1034.684 16.73780 13.97733
9  1036.408 14.20320 12.49314
10 1028.872 21.34184 19.78916
11 1029.830 20.41493 18.86599
12 1030.389 22.78061 17.72866
13 1029.418 22.06944 19.00447
14 1029.960 22.13652 18.35963
15 1029.157 32.32527 17.19872
16 1032.052 16.94312 16.99502
17 1032.407 18.65000 16.23179
18 1030.795 20.45486 17.73539
19 1030.483 20.52841 18.08316
20 1031.352 19.85577 17.20990
21 1032.251 15.87167 16.98465
22 1035.141 17.74500 13.23838
23 1029.903 25.76326 17.68064
24 1032.351 18.97481 16.22997
25 1027.843 27.17222 19.78695
26 1032.539 18.95833 16.01488
27 1033.245 18.82787 15.22004
28 1029.821 23.73984 18.19190
29 1029.914 24.68182 17.89026
30 1030.952 27.13333 16.17911
31 1032.043 19.55782 16.46818
32 1027.762 25.93333 20.13492
33 1033.475 18.37057 15.04696
34 1032.662 16.13277 16.45258
35 1030.969 22.83163 17.04425
36 1032.856 16.40816 16.16999
37 1034.917 16.57910 13.73898
38 1029.530 22.86957 18.70982
39 1029.283 27.62719 18.01809
40 1034.083 16.54717 14.71488
41 1030.551 21.91667 17.71784
42 1033.386 16.73790 15.48629
43 1033.967 15.88802 14.98579
44 1029.661 21.57576 18.82337
45 1029.612 23.28889 18.52730
46 1029.799 21.45833 18.68730
47 1030.928 22.71181 17.11599
48 1031.717 19.98588 16.75930
49 1030.169 23.28598 17.88077
50 1031.476 20.30702 16.97314
51 1030.366 20.18590 18.28896
52 1031.687 22.09792 16.35971
53 1033.666 15.82960 15.34795
54 1029.295 29.78125 17.56115
55 1028.032 22.92172 20.44113
56 1029.317 26.36553 18.23772
57 1029.443 25.46237 18.27741
58 1033.560 15.31183 15.57765
59 1031.092 24.26282 16.60651
60 1028.863 24.50521 19.14858
61 1031.629 17.66830 17.33869
62 1028.987 23.38605 19.23521
63 1031.517 19.58796 17.07345
64 1028.977 26.51111 18.60405
65 1029.984 14.37500 19.92848
66 1029.964 25.02451 17.76104
67 1029.512 25.02851 18.28642
68 1033.758 16.55208 15.09177
69 1031.711 17.39744 17.29828
```

Comment: Sorry missed that point. I remove my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interpolate onto a regular 2D grid, then recast that back into x, y, z co-ordinates:

```r
library(ggplot2)

with(df, interp::interp(x = x, y = y, z = z, nx = 500, ny = 500)) |>
  interp::interp2xyz() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(fill = after_stat(level_mid)), bins = 17) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(NULL, n.breaks = 17,
                    colors = c('#ffffc8', '#f6b732', '#c52300', '#7d0025'),
                    labels = ~ifelse(.x %% 2 == 0, .x, '')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(10, 'mm'))
```

[image]